# Can't get data from joined tables in dataset when using a CollectionView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a dataset with two datatables in it, with the correct relations added. In the datatable Inventory I have a field with a userId that is connected to the DataTable People.

I use a BindingListCollection for sorting and filtering.

```
this.ita.Fill(this.DsInventory._Inventory);
this.ata.Fill(this.DsInventory.People);
this.cv = new BindingListCollectionView(this.DsInventory._Inventory.DefaultView);
this.DataContext = this.cv;
```

The problem now is: how can I bind the Name column from the People dataTable to to the form I have? This Name column is not in the CollectionView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name isn't in your DefaultView because the DefaultView you're using is for _Inventory so change the DefaultView or create a new one on the dataset to include the peoples table.

Comment: Ok, so I need to create a custom DataView that includes both tables?
Will that give me trouble when i want to insert new records or update one? I only want to update the _Inventory table, now I do this using the CollectionView with the DefaultView